# Android how to assign the time for the appointment to specific person

Tags: android, android-gridview

Now i am devloping an app for the Doctor to book the appointment,i have defined 20 slots and 30 min each.starting from 10 Am to 8 Pm and it is for today only.Now my problem is how to assign the time slot for one user only.Example:if A person  book a time 10:00Am other person cannot allowed to that time.how to save that time to  the user and disable the time for other user.the person also allowed to edit their info and timings if any one is available.The user have book the appointment for today only.Actually I am not using API because i am just make an demo.What i am trying

```
public class BookingScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
GridView gridView;
EditText nameEt, mobileEt, emailEt;
String selectedItem, date;
TextView gridText;
Button book;
SQLiteDatabase db;
String phone, name, email;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookind_screen);
    db = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase("SlotBooking.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    getIntentValues();
    initViews();
}
private void getIntentValues() {
    email = getIntent().getStringExtra("emailEt");
    phone = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
    name = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameEt");
}
private void initViews() {
    nameEt = findViewById(R.id.name_book);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        nameEt.setText(name);
        nameEt.setEnabled(false);
    }
    mobileEt = findViewById(R.id.mobile_book);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
        mobileEt.setText(phone);
    }
    emailEt = findViewById(R.id.email_book);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        emailEt.setText(email);
    }
    emailEt.addTextChangedListener(emailWatcher);
    mobileEt.addTextChangedListener(mobileWatcher);
    book = findViewById(R.id.booknow);
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    setupGrid();

    book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!nameEt.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !mobileEt.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !emailEt.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                if ( checkValidation()) {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("Name", nameEt.getText().toString());
                    values.put("MobileNumber", mobileEt.getText().toString());
                    values.put("EmailAddress", emailEt.getText().toString());
                    values.put("VisitStatus", "Booked");
                    values.put("BookingTime", selectedItem);
                    values.put("BookingDate", date);
                    db.insert("BookingRecord", null, values);
                    Intent in = new Intent(BookingScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    if (mobileEt.getText().toString().length() != 10) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Number is Not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Invalid Emailaddress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All Fields Are Mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
}

private void setupGrid() {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("10:00 AM");
    values.add("10:30 AM");
    values.add("11:00 AM");
    values.add("11:30 AM");
    values.add("12:00 AM");
    values.add("12:30 PM");
    values.add("01:00 PM");
    values.add("01:30 PM");
    values.add("02:00 PM");
    values.add("02:30 PM");
    values.add("03:00 PM");
    values.add("03:30 PM");
    values.add("04:00 PM");
    values.add("04:30 PM");
    values.add("05:00 PM");
    values.add("05:30 PM");
    values.add("06:00 PM");
    values.add("06:30 PM");
    values.add("07:00 PM");
    values.add("07:30 PM");
    values.add("08:00 PM");
    gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    final TimeAdapter timeAdapter = new TimeAdapter(this, values);
    gridView.setAdapter(timeAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            selectedItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            timeAdapter.setSelectedPosition(i);
            timeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkValidation() {
    boolean ret = true;
    if (!Validation.isEmailAddress(emailEt, true)) ret = false;
    if (!Validation.isPhoneNumber(mobileEt, false)) ret = false;

    return ret;
}

TextWatcher emailWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Validation.isEmailAddress(emailEt, true);
    }
};

TextWatcher mobileWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Validation.isPhoneNumber(mobileEt, false);
    }
};
```

}

TimeAdapter.Class it is used to the change the grid view(time slots)color of selected slots.

```
  public class TimeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<String> time;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private int selectedPosition = -1;

public TimeAdapter(Context c, List<String> time) {
    mContext = c;
    this.time = time;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

public int getCount() {
    return time.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return time.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView gridText;
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_text, null);
    gridText = (TextView) convertView;
    gridText.setText(String.valueOf(time.get(position)));
    if (position == selectedPosition) {
        gridText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(convertView.getContext(), R.color.colorSecondary));
        gridText.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(convertView.getContext(), R.drawable.border_green));
    } else {
        gridText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(convertView.getContext(), R.color.colorbook));
        gridText.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(convertView.getContext(), R.drawable.border));
    }
    return convertView;
}

public void setSelectedPosition(int i) {
    selectedPosition = i;
}
```

}

Now i want to save the selected time slot for the desired user and retrieve the time when the user want to change their booking at that time enable only not booked time slots by the otherwise.if all time slots are booked  disable all the time.sorry for the bad english I am new to stack and android.I need some guide or any example for that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a time slot class:

```
class timeSlot{
    private String timeslot;
    private Boolean available

   //Constructor
   timeSlot(String timeSlot, Boolean available){
       this.timeSlot = timeSlot;
       this.available = available;
   }
   //Check Availability
   public Boolean isAvailable(){
       return available;
   }
}
```

Whenever you assign a timeslot, check if the timeslot is available using the `isAvailable` function. If it is available, assign it and set `available` to `false`

---

EDIT: This however will not stop you from creating 2 timeslots for the same time. Another approach could be to store all timeslots in a database, with the slot time as primary key, and a column for availability. From the table you can query the slot and check the availability.

Comment: ok thanks anuraag...i will try and let u know..do u have any examples related to that